# The script does not read the correct values in filtered cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with filtered contents from other Sheet with the formula

```
=filter('Main'!C1:C400, 'Main'!B1:B400='Accepted')
```

And in the sheet it shows the correct values, but when I am trying to access to the contents of the cell through Apps script shows a different value.

For example the filtered contents are

```
C1: Apple
C2: Pear
C3: Orange
```

So, through the script we want to get the value of the cell C1, that is expected to be Apple, however it returns "Orange".

```
function readColumnC() {
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C2').getValue()
}
```

How could read the values of filtered cell with the formula =filter?

Edit: The issue was not only due to the filter in the second sheet. It was in the Main sheet, it was added a filter view, for example, sorting it alphabetically. In that scenario the values don't match. The filtered sheet does change, in its showing values, but the links to its values internally they are different.

Comment: Could you please try to log `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()`?

Comment: I am at the correct sheet and it shows, for example we have the sheets Main and Fruits, and the filter is in Fruits. The ActiveSheet is Fruits, but the value I get is wrong.

Comment: I have reproduced what you have posted and it does return the expected value for me. Could you share a copy of the data?

Comment: I am afraid that the real data is confidential and cannot be shared. I will check how to reproduce it without the real data.

Comment: `we want to get the value of the cell C1`<>`...getRange('C2')` C1 or C2?

Comment: Well, sorry with the differences of the code and the exposition. We want to get the value of a cell, for example the C2, to be the same as the code. However, in reality, it would be read all cells. But the values given were not the same as the cell. And that was the weird thing, and the only special thing is the =filter.

Comment: Editing the question, as there are more conditionals. There are filters in the main page as well, and for example have been sorted alphabetically. There is when the values are not correct.

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce your error. Could you share the way you are sorting the data in the Sheet `Main`? It would also be helpful if you could make a copy, avoiding the confidential data and leaving only what is related to the question?

Comment: I can share this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mj2A8YCak3LDaktvcKLJvA4Czs_e-CK1ozPU--YL7rA/edit?usp=sharing
You have the a filter view in Main that sorts by Z-A called filter-Sort-Z-A. If it is enables the value of the first row in Fruits sheet would not be the one expected.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand where the error is, I have tried it and the values I am receiving are correct.